# Perform app linking in an Oreo TV app to use google assistant for in-app search

Tags: android, deep-linking, actions-on-google, android-tv, applinks

I am currently developing a sample TV app to perform in-app search using google assistant. I created an agent in dialogflow and also coded the fulfillment part.

In order to perform app linking in my sample app, I followed the steps provided in android developers site. I have secured website to link my app.

According to the procedure, I created the assestlinks.json file using the app links assistant in android studio. Placed the file at the root folder of the domain as well i.e, "https://domainname/.well-known/assetlinks.json". But when I click on "link and verify" button in app links assistant, the error "We could not associate your app with the selected domain.Please make sure the Digital Asset Links File is uploaded to the correct domain" displays.
But when I click on the link,I am able to see the file at that location.

Please help me in correcting this issue as I am not able to proceed since a long time due to this.

Answer (score 0):

To use the Assistant for in-app search, you need to use a content provider. With your content provider, you specify the deep links explicitly in the search results.

https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/searchable

For more details about how the Google Assistant works on Android TV check out this [blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/10/video-playback-with-google-assistant-on.html).

Comment: I completely agree with your explanation.But this works on app side.But it does not answer my question.If you have a website and app which can respond to the google action, then an "open with" dialog appears on screen which I want to avoid and want  my app to be used by default to respond to this action.In order to do this, json file is used which has to be placed at the right path.This is where I'm facing problem.